# Combine plot of file and splot of function in one graph with gnuplot

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

i want to plot a path of lines on a splot of a function in one graph.
My code:

```
reset
#set output 'potential_tr_pfad3.tex'
set terminal tikz color size 18cm, 8cm
unset key

set view map
set samples 80, 80
set isosamples 80, 80

plot 'tr_path.dat' with circles lc rgb "#90EE90" fs transparent solid 0.15 border,\
'tr_path.dat' u 1:2 with linespoints lw 2 lc rgb "#000000"

set xr [x=-4:4]
set yr [y=-11:2]

potential(x,y) = 5*(x**2+y**2+8*x+6*y)**2+5*(x**2+y**2-6*x+8*y)**2+1000*y

set contour base
set cntrparam bspline
set cntrparam levels discrete 20000,10000,2500,0,-2500,-5000, -6000,-7000
do for [t=1:8] {
set linetype t lc rgb "#888888"
}

set xlabel "X" 
set ylabel "Y" 
set zlabel '{/Symbol P}' enhanced
set zlabel  offset character 7, 9, 0

potential(x,y) = 5*(x**2+y**2+8*x+6*y)**2+5*(x**2+y**2-6*x+8*y)**2+1000*y
set xr [x=-4:4]
set yr [y=-10:1]

set style textbox opaque margins  0.5,  0.5 fc  bgnd noborder linewidth  1.0
set cntrlabel start 0  format "%16.0f" font ",6" interval 100
unset surface

splot potential(x,y) with lines lc rgb "#000000",\
potential(x,y) with labels boxed notitle
```

with the data file:

```
0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000  1.0000000
0.00000000e+000  -1.00000000e+000  2.0000000 
-7.21690590e-002 -2.37121212e+000  4.0000000
```

My solution until now was to combine the two tikz-pictures in LaTeX. But there must be a better way without getting in trouble with graph boundaries. Any ideas?

Greetings and Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the problem here is that `splot` with contour and `plot` with circles cannot be used together.
One solution would be to plot the contour data into a table and then plot it together with one `plot` command.
I've rearranged or rewritten your code a bit. I guess this should come close what you want to achieve and can be tweaked further. Output below created with gnuplot 5.2.6 and wxt terminal.

**Code:**

```
### plot contour data together with something else
reset session
unset key

set view map
set samples 80, 80
set isosamples 80, 80

set xr [x=-4:4]
set yr [y=-11:2]

potential(x,y) = 5*(x**2+y**2+8*x+6*y)**2+5*(x**2+y**2-6*x+8*y)**2+1000*y
set contour base
set cntrparam bspline
set cntrparam levels discrete 20000,10000,2500,0,-2500,-5000, -6000,-7000
unset surface

# write contour data to table
set table $Potential
    splot potential(x,y)
unset table

set xlabel "X" 
set ylabel "Y" 
set zlabel '{/Symbol P}' enhanced
set zlabel  offset character 7, 9, 0

set style textbox opaque margins  0.5,  0.5 fc  bgnd noborder linewidth  1.0

plot $Potential u 1:2 w l lc rgb "#888888",\
     '' every 100 w labels boxed  font ",6" notitle, \
     'MyData.dat' u 1:2:3 w circles lc rgb "#90EE90",\
     '' u 1:2:3 w lp lw 2 lc rgb "#000000"
### end of code
```

`MyData.dat`

```
0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000  1.0000000
0.00000000e+000  -1.00000000e+000  2.0000000 
-7.21690590e-002 -2.37121212e+000  4.0000000
```

**Result:**

[image]